# Run Excel Macro via VBA in Acces

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm new at Access and VBA and I wanted to created an automated process. 
But I think I'm all over my head with this one. I'm trying to make a macro in Access that:

1. checks if the file exists
2. opens the excel file and runs the macro
3. imports the results

I'm trying to get the macro to run the macro in, but it seems a lost cause.
Can someone assist me?

```
Private Sub Main_btn_Click()

    Dim fileInfoToBeImported(3, 1)

    fileInfoToBeImported(0, 0) = "Stock_CC"
    fileInfoToBeImported(0, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Stock_getdata.xlsm"
    fileInfoToBeImported(0, 2) = "GetStock"

    fileInfoToBeImported(1, 0) = "Wips_CC"
    fileInfoToBeImported(1, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Wips_getdata.xlsm"
    fileInfoToBeImported(1, 2) = "Update"

    fileInfoToBeImported(2, 0) = "CCA_cc"
    fileInfoToBeImported(2, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\SLAcc.xls"
    fileInfoToBeImported(2, 2) = "Read_CCA"

    fileInfoToBeImported(3, 0) = "Eps_cc"
    fileInfoToBeImported(3, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\eps.xlsm"
    fileInfoToBeImported(3, 2) = "Update"

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'LOOP DOOR DE BESTANDEN
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim loopIndex As Integer
    For loopIndex = 0 To UBound(fileInfoToBeImported, 1)
        RunMacroInExcel fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 0), fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 1), fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 2)
        transferSpreadsheetFunction fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 0), fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 1)
    Next loopIndex
End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'LAAT MACRO IN EXCEL LOPEN EN IMPORTEERT GEGEVENS
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub RunMacroInExcel(ByVal Xl As Object)

'Step 1:  Start Excel, then open the target workbook.
   Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Xl.Workbooks.Open (fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 0))

'Step 2:  Make Excel visible
   Xl.Visible = True

'Step 3:  Run the target macro
   Xl.Run (fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 2))

'Step 4:  Close and save the workbook, then close Excel
   Xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
    Xl.Quit

'Step 5:  Memory Clean up.
   Set Xl = Nothing


End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'IMPORTEERT GEGEVENS
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub transferSpreadsheetFunction(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal fileName As String)
    If FileExist(fileName) Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , tableName, fileName, True
    Else
    Dim Msg As String
        Msg = "Bestand niet gevonden" & Str(Err.Number) & Err.Source & Err.Description
        MsgBox (Msg)
      End If
End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'IS HET BESTAND AANWEZIG?
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function FileExist(sTestFile As String) As Boolean
   Dim lSize As Long
   On Error Resume Next
      lSize = -1
      lSize = FileLen(sTestFile)
   If lSize > -1 Then
      FileExist = True
   Else
      FileExist = False
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
Private Sub Main_btn_Click()

    Dim fileInfo(0 To 3, 0 To 2) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    fileInfo(0, 0) = "Stock_CC"
    fileInfo(0, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Stock_getdata.xlsm"
    fileInfo(0, 2) = "GetStock"

    fileInfo(1, 0) = "Wips_CC"
    fileInfo(1, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Wips_getdata.xlsm"
    fileInfo(1, 2) = "Update"

    fileInfo(2, 0) = "CCA_cc"
    fileInfo(2, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\SLAcc.xls"
    fileInfo(2, 2) = "Read_CCA"

    fileInfo(3, 0) = "Eps_cc"
    fileInfo(3, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\eps.xlsm"
    fileInfo(3, 2) = "Update"


    For i = 0 To UBound(fileInfo, 1)

        RunMacroInExcel fileInfo(i, 1), _
                        fileInfo(i, 2)

        transferSpreadsheetFunction fileInfo(i, 0), fileInfo(i, 1)

    Next i

End Sub


Private Sub RunMacroInExcel(fName As String, macroName As String)
    Dim XL As Object, wb As Object

    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    XL.Visible = True
    Set wb = XL.Workbooks.Open(fName)

    XL.Run macroName
    wb.Close True

    XL.Quit
    Set XL = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub transferSpreadsheetFunction(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal fileName As String)
    Dim Msg As String
    If FileExist(fileName) Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , tableName, fileName, True
    Else
        Msg = "Bestand niet gevonden " & Str(Err.Number) & Err.Source & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg
    End If
End Sub

Function FileExist(sTestFile As String) As Boolean
   FileExist = (Len(Dir(sTestFile, vbNormal)) > 0)
End Function
```